# How to populate a vector upon construction of object in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, stdvector

I am trying to create a class that has a member of type `std::vector` and I want this vector to be filled with number 2 when an instance of this class is created:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class primes{
   private:
     vector <int> myvec;
     myvec.push_back(2);
};
```

But the compiler gives me:

> error: ‘myvec’ does not name a type

Comment: Oops messed up in typing in my question

Comment: Ya the message says"myvec" does not name a type

Comment: That is *why you include the error message in your post when you ask about an error that you're getting* ...

Comment: You should reformulate your question and its title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class primes{
   private:
     vector <int> myvec;
     myvec.push_back(2);   // <-- this can not be placed here
};
```

compiler expects there declaration / definition of member or method (member function). You can not place there code such as `myvec.push_back(2);`. That must be placed inside the body of some method:

```
class primes {
private:
    std::vector<int> myvec;

public:
    void addPrime(int num) {
        myvec.push_back(num);
    }
};
```

or in case you want to construct instance of `primes` with `vector` that will already contain number 2:

```
class primes {
public:
    primes() : myvec(std::vector<int>(1, 2)) { }

private:
    std::vector<int> myvec;
};
```

or if you need to populate this vector with more of them:

```
int PRIMES[] = { 1, 2, 3, 5, 7 };
const int PCOUNT = sizeof(PRIMES) / sizeof(PRIMES[0]);

class primes {
public:
    primes()
     : myvec(std::vector<int>(PRIMES, PRIMES + PCOUNT)) { }

private:
    std::vector<int> myvec;
};
```

Comment: Is there a way that I could just create the vector so that it already contains the 2?

Comment: @user2803001 you can also say `vector <int> myvec = {2};` if you have C++11.

Comment: @user2803001: You're welcome :) And in case you decide to initialize more primes, see my edit ;)

Answer (score 3):

`myvec.push_back(2);` should be inside a method.

You cannot write it inside the class declaration like you did.

Example:

```
class primes
{
   public:
     void Add( int num )
     {
       myvec.push_back( num ); // is in a method
     }
   private:
     vector <int> myvec;
     // myvec.push_back( num ); // <-- Illegal in c++
};
```

If you use C++11 and you want to initialize the vector containing the value 2:

```
class primes
{
   private:
     vector <int> myvec{2};
     //                ^^^
};
```